# Excel - Automatic allocation of preferences

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Edit: [Example file available here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ifcK9jpVYTVkrDvrUfIKvM2QdSjytquN/view?usp=sharing)

I'm not a super experienced Excel user, but I'm trying to automate using IF/AND/INDEX/MATCH to assign yes/no to preferences which competitively listed people have chosen from a list of about 300 choices. Each person has listed 4 preferences, there's over 1000 people in the process, and each person gets one preference out of four. A simplified hypothetical version of it is a situation where I want automate the allocation of employee shifts at a restaurant, with the employee data listed with the best workers at the top and the worst ones at the bottom.

Traditionally the Shift Allocation sheet has been done manually, which is fine when you have seven days of the week and maybe 30 employees. But if I have 300 days of the week and 1000 employees, I don't want to manually allocate each one to their preferences. Or if I do have a manual input, I want it to automate enough shift allocation beforehand so it doesn't take up as much time.

Ideally the automated formula to assign the yes/no indicator for the shift in the Shift Allocation would look at the first preference (day of the week) the person has listed in the Employee Data sheet, check the Shifts Available sheet to find the day of the week and then look at the number of shifts available in column K, if column K is more than 0, assign YES to that employee's preference on the Shift Allocation sheet, then move on to the next employee.

The employees are listed by who gets first pick, so in theory some people at the bottom may not get the shifts they preferenced, or there may need to be other manual changes made after the automatic allocation process for other reasons.

I tried VLOOKUP but the lookup logic wasn't broad enough, so I need something like an INDEX/MATCH parameter to find the shift places available in column K of the Shifts Available sheet after finding the day of the week in Column A.

This is about as far as I got with the code

```
=IF(AND(INDEX('Shifts Available'!$A$2:$K$8, MATCH('Employee Data'!$A$2,0)), 'Shifts Available'![K-column cell corresponding to the day of the week, unsure how to do this? Keep it in the INDEX?]) >=0)"Yes", "No")
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You mind putting up a screen shot with the pertinent info removed?

Comment: what is the "4 preferences" options to? is it a numbered data or text?

Comment: @Rookie Please see linked file.

Comment: @terry-w Doc attached in edited post.

Comment: @p._phidot_ In the real file it will be text, please see linked doc in post.

Comment: I have checked your sample sheet and need you to address two questions: 1) Are the employees on the `Employee Data Preferences` ranked already? E.g. if you need to allocate a Monday shift will you pick Samhill before Allbright as he is above Allbright on the list? 2) If you need to allocate 5 shifts to Monday but you only have 4 staff has Monday as their first preference, are you going to pick the first staff that has Monday as their second preference? What if that staff has Tuesday as 1st pick and you have spaces left in Tuesday. Are you going to put him/her to Tuesday or Monday?

Comment: In addition, who will you choose for Friday between Peters Alison and Seison Evie? Perter ranked first on the employee list but Friday is his second preference. Seison ranked sixth on the employee list but Friday is his first preference.

Comment: @TerryW Thanks for your help. 1) The employees on that Employee Data Preferences sheet are already ranked, so yes, I want Samhill to be allocated to a shift before Allbright. 2) No, because in real-world application the sheet is used for something unrelated to employee shifts completely, it was just the best metaphor I could come up with when making the dummy sheet. In the real-world application, the "employees" being allocated to

Comment: @TerryW Sorry, I'm a comments n00b.
2) In reality the sheet is used for something unrelated to shifts, it was just the best metaphor I could come up with, and I rarely have preferences that have more spaces available than people wanting them, and if I do it's NBD.
1) The employees in Employee Data Preferences are already ranked.

Comment: @TerryW
3) Sorry, should have thought about that one. The real process involves each person only receiving one preference, not multiple employee shifts. Apologies for the confusion. So in the real work application, Alison would be put against Sunday, and Evie would be put against Friday.

Comment: So even though each employee will have four preferences, the logic to allocate the shift is by first choice and then by the rank of the employee, i.e. if you want to allocate 5 Friday shifts you first look at all the employees that have Friday as their first choice, and then select the top 5 employees based on their rank on the list. Also what do you mean by **NBD**?

Comment: imho : nbd = no big deal | Dear Cara, Q1) how many shift there is per day? (and is it the same on weekends? Q2) how many people are allocated per shift ?

Comment: using my assumptions.. here is a proposed [solution](https://utpmy-my.sharepoint.com/personal/mohammad_g03606_utp_edu_my/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=098220b4615ac4bd8bd5c6189ddd1cfc1&authkey=AQbUH8hc9eyuddUX6LXcT1o&e=3RO5Xk) .. hope you can verify the assumptions and way forward for C123 cell concern. /(^_^)>